# check if an entry has a certain playa parent

Tags: ee2, categories, php, playa

I'm looping through my entries, and I want to check if my entry has a certain entry as his playa parent.

Right now I'm using this code, which works, **but I'm wondering if it can be done without PHP.**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
    <?php $hasParent = false; ?>

    {project_categorie}
      {if segment_2 == url_title}
        <?php $hasParent = true; ?>
      {/if}
    {/project_categorie}

    <?php if($hasParent){ echo "wooptidoo"; }?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

so, this runs through my playa related entries, checks to see if the url_title matches my quert ( segment_2 in this case ) and displays this **once**.

Another example of this functionality would be: checking to see if you entry is in a certain category. f.ex:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
    <?php $isInCategory = false; ?>

    {categories}
      {if segment_2 == category_url_title}
        <?php $isInCategory = true; ?>
      {/if}
    {/categories}

    <?php if($isInCategory){ echo "wooptidoo"; }?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

can this be done without having to use PHP ?

**EDIT:

--------------------**

Ok, I have not idea why I didn't think of this before, but this works perfectly..

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
    {project_categorie}
      {if segment_2 == url_title}
        wooptidoo
      {/if}
    {/project_categorie}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

stuuupid. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an entry has a parent with the `{exp:playa:parents}` tag, it accepts all the channel entries parameters also. Something like this could work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="channel" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        wooptidoo
        {if no_parents} ... {/if}
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You could also use a addon like Low's Seg2Cat to filter the entries even more:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="channel" category="{segment_2_category_id}" "entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

Comment: This might be a better answer. I wasn't sure what @janvl meant by using Playa when I saw the code examples relating to categories, so I got kinda thrown off. My code pertains to categories more than it does playa.

Comment: this won't work, because that will output the "wooptidoo" for every playa parent. I just want to check if the entry has one specific playa parent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my new free add-on. It's not 100% ready for prime time, but that method should work. I do stuff like that all the time. Let me know if there are methods missing that you need.

http://objectivehtml.com/entries

Edit... Not 100% sure those methods exist currently, but here would be a good proposed API.

```
{exp:entries:has_parent_category entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {if no_results}
        This does not belong to parent category
    {/if}

{/exp:entries:has_parent_category}

{exp:entries:in_category entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {if no_results}
        This does not belong to category
    {/if}
{/exp:entries:in_category}
```